# Opencv Logistic Regression load failed

Tags: c++, opencv, templates, serialization, namespaces

I am using opencv's `cv::ml::LogisticRegression` class and have serialized it and saved it to file using the `cv::Algorithm::save` method, and am trying to load the file back into a `Ptr<LogisticRegression>` using `cv::ml::LogisticRegression::load`, as described in the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d6/df9/classcv_1_1ml_1_1LogisticRegression.html#af3a20a4bc0f92ca2c5c1a2e46713b2f0), my save code looks like this:

```
Ptr<cv::ml::LogisticRegression> logisReg = logisticRegression(features_train, labels_train);
logisReg->save("mFileName");
```

And load code (different place)

```
Ptr<cv::ml::LogisticRegression> logisReg = cv::ml::LogisticRegression::load("mFileName", "Logisitic Regression Classifier");
```

The save code works fine, and the serialized file content makes sense (plain text). However, when I tried to compile the load it, I got this error:

```
main.cpp:97:5: error: no matching function for call to 'load'
    cv::ml::LogisticRegression::load("logisReg.auracle", "Logisitic Regression Classifier");
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/local/opt/opencv3/include/opencv2/core.hpp:3074:44: note: candidate template ignored: couldn't infer template argument '_Tp'
    template<typename _Tp> static Ptr<_Tp> load(const String& filename, const String& objname=String())
                                       ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you give is of version 3.2.0-dev, which has function:

`static Ptr<LogisticRegression> load(const String &filepath, const String &nodeName=String())`

but version before 3.1 only has an inherited template function:

`template<typename _Tp >
static Ptr<_Tp> load (const String &filename, const String &objname=String())`

I guess you are using opencv lib version before 3.1, try instantiate the template function explicitly:

`load<LogisticRegression>()`